# it is happened about "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:@192.164.6.77:1521:BDSS" when spark connect oracle

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

the follow is my code.

firstly,

`./spark-shell --master spark://172.11.11.11:7077 --jars /opt/beh/bin/ojdbc14.jar`

secondly,

```
`import java.util.Properties`

`val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)`

`val properties = new Properties()`

`properties.setProperty("user", "xxx")`

`properties.setProperty("password", "xxx")`

`val url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.11.11.11:1521:BDSS"`

`val people = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"code_pay_mode",properties)`
```

it is happened about "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:@192.164.6.77:1521:BDSS" when executing `val people = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"code_pay_mode",properties)`

Comment: Can you connect via a regular scala application, without the sparkContext, just a regular jdbc query?

Answer (score 0):

[Comment JIRA Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6913?focusedCommentId=14519124&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14519124)

Seems it can be related to your issue.
I mean --jars /opt/beh/bin/ojdbc14.jar